# Why does slice push work in redux but not concat?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Recently I change to slice and I seeing some odd behavior can someone explain:

```
const initialState = {
  []
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loadUsers(state, action) {
      state = state.concat(action.payload);
    },
  },
});
```

when i do something like this the state wont change and payload dont add to state array

i can go like

```
for(let i=0; i < action.payload.length; i++) {
    state.push(action.payload[i]
}
```

and everything work fine, then I realized if name the state initial state like:

```
const initialState = {
  users: [],
};
```

Then I can go like:

```
state.users = state.users.concat(action.payload);
```

on **loadUsers** reducer and this work fine too
can someone explain why ***concat*** wont work on first attempt when i have initial state of [] without naming it

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not `push` or `concat`, but the fact that

```js
state = something
```

will never do anything.

Redux Toolkit watches *the object in the variable `state`* for modifications - but that assignment *throws away that object and puts a new object into the variable* instead of changing it.

That cannot be observed.

Instead, you can do

```js
return something
```

For more information, see [Writing Reducers with `immer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers), especially [resetting and replacing state](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state), which says:

> A common mistake is to try assigning `state = someValue` directly. This will not work! This only points the local state variable to a different reference. That is neither mutating the existing state object/array in memory, nor returning an entirely new value, so Immer does not make any actual changes.

Comment: thank you i read and understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the previous answer, to make one distinction. You should not attempt to mutate the entire state as in the line

```
State = something
```

But you can and should mutate state properties in this way, in fact it is one of the major benefits of redux toolkit and immer, so

```
State.prop = something
```

Is ok.
This is a good time to reiterate this kind of state mutation is only ok in redux toolkit where immer is doing it’s work.

Again here is the link to the relevant docs

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).